# Restore a database dump in ubuntu server

Tags: mysql

My problem is that my backup is on desktop of windows and I have to restore it on ubuntu server.So please suggest me any command for restoring.
I was used
        mysql -u xxxx -pxxxx database < x.sql
but it cant found this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to ubuntu terminal.

Then type

`cd /home/{username}/Desktop/`  here `username` is the `username` for the machine u can see it inside home

Now u are on Desktop

Then type

```
mysql -u xxx -pxxxx database < x.sql
```

Comment: but here i was working with windows and use putty for ubuntu server. Is there any way to copy a dump from one server to another

Comment: ho then u need to copy it via ssh check this links how to do it http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1414293 https://community.freescale.com/thread/220596